# escape apostrophe in thymeleaf variable

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I'm trying to escape the apostrophes in the value of a variable that is passed as a string parameter using thymeleaf. My code looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" th:id="${'delete'+document['oid_pj']}"
                th:if="${document['utilisateur'] == session.utilisateur}"
                th:onclick="'deletePj(\''+${document['oid_pj']}+'\',\''+ ${document['url']} +'\');'">
```

and when the html page is interpreted it looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="deleteAS8bo00000F1T" onclick="deletePj('AS8bo00000F1T','//20150007/GIWkE0000FHUI//Creation d'un service GtMonitor.doc');">
```

so the apostrophe from "d'un" closes the parameter before it's meant to.

Does anyone know how can i escape it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before passing `${document['url']}` (the value containing single quote) to the javascript function, clean it first by replacing `'` with `\'`. Use `th:with` to create a local variable which will be used to store the cleaned value. Use `#strings.replace` to do the replacement. To prevent compilation errors, use html entity `&apos;` instead of `'` when replacing

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" 
            th:with='cleaned=${#strings.replace(document["url"], "&apos;", "\&apos;")}'
            th:onclick="'deletePj(\''+${document['oid_pj']}+'\',\''+ ${cleaned} +'\');'"/>
```

**Output :**

```
<input type="button" onclick="deletePj('AS8bo00000F1T','//20150007/GIWkE0000FHUI//Creation d\'un service GtMonitor.doc');" value="Reconciliation">
```

Comment: There isn't a built-in operator for ThymeLeaf that does this?  Almost any field can contain apostrophes.  E.g. `Bob's Widget` in the widget title field. Any name field just about anywhere. ...  Does anyone know something more concise and general?  I'm a ThymeLeaf noob.  So, sorry if I'm missing something here ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try switching around how you are using quotes

```
onclick='"deletePj(\""+${document["oid_pj"]}+"\",\""+ ${document["url"]} +"\");"'>
```